# How to display India country first in country selection drop down list in WordPress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

How to display India country first in country selection drop down list in WordPress

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? What didn't work, and where exactly did you get stuck? Please read [ask].

Comment: i have add woocommerce country field in wordpress login.
on country filed i have display the India country first in drodown

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code in your **functions.php** file to select a default country in checkout page drop-down.

```
/**
 * Change the default state and country on the checkout page
 */
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_country', 'change_default_checkout_country' );

function change_default_checkout_country() {
  return 'IN'; // country code
}
```

Please let me know if code works.